# CAN bus libraries for STM32F103 in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, can-bus

I need to implement CAN communication between two STM32F103 microcontroller boards. I am finding it difficult to get libraries for the same. Can anyone please suggest where I can find working CAN bus libraries for STM32F103?

Comment: Have you tried stm32duino.com forum pages?  http://www.stm32duino.com/search.php?keywords=CAN+bus

Comment: Yes, but there are no valid libraries in that @smajli